# Fastest method on x86-64 to check if pointer range straddles an N byte aligned address?

Tags: c++, alignment, bit-manipulation, x86-64, simd

Given a pointer to a T, I'd like to determine if the T straddles an N byte aligned address. In practice I really only care about whether 0-5 byte size objects straddle 8 or 16 byte byte boundaries, but I wrote up this general version:

```
template<class T, unsigned long N>
bool straddlesBoundary(T* obj)
{
    unsigned long before = (unsigned long)obj & ~(N-1);
    unsigned long after  = ((unsigned long)obj + sizeof(T) - 1) & ~(N-1);
    return before != after;
}
```

Basically, round the address down to the nearest N byte aligned address, then take the pointer increment by the size of T minus one (because T ending right on the next boundary doesn't count as a straddle) and round it down to the nearest N byte aligned address, and if they match you know it doesn't straddle.

Is there a faster way to do this? I just made this up, I don't know if there's a standard check.

Edit: Note, I am assuming T's that are smaller than N.

Comment: Well, `#define ~(N-1) BA` and substuting accordingly would help a little.

Comment: Why do you care?  Have you measured your program's performance and found this to be a bottleneck?

Comment: @MikeSeymour N is known at compile time, so wouldn't doing this save you some calculations?  Or would any compiler optimize this out automatically?

Comment: @MattPhillips: Sorry, by "what?", I meant "What do you mean?". `~(N-1)` isn't a valid macro name and even if it were, replacing it with an undefined name would just make compilation fail. If you meant replacing occurrences of `~(N-1)` with `BA` and then adding `#define BA ~(N-1)` to get the preprocessor to undo the change, then you'll end up with identical code after preprocessing. In any event, `~(N-1)` is just as much a compile-time constant as `N`, so there's no need to try to optimise that calculation.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Doh!! Lol yes that was just a typo.  Don't use #defines that often.  I meand simply replacing `~(N-1)` with `BA` at compile time.  Your other observations duly noted.

Comment: @MattPhillips: OK, in that case the answer is no. Replacing one compile-time constant with another won't improve performance, although it could improve readability if you do it sensibly (but macros are rarely sensible).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ok I didn't realize `~(N-1)` was a compile-time constant--its value is known (knowable) at compile-time but that doesn't entail that the compiler actually calculates it.  But I'll take your word for it that it does.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: I'm experimenting with micro-optimizing some decompression code by opportunistically using MMX/SSE when the current byte is aligned and/or when I can compensate for it being misaligned with a mask (but my fix for misalignment doesn't work when an aligned address is straddled by the amount I'm going to read, thus my need to efficiently filter those cases).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Most modern compilers will apply constant folding to template arguments. I can verify this by looking at the assembly output from passing GCC the "-S" flag in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
unsigned long offset = (unsigned long)obj & (N-1);
return offset > N - sizeof(T);
```

(this code, as yours, only works if N is a power of 2.)

Comment: Oh, duh. This is definitely better :) I'll wait awhile to check accepted to see if any other answers come in though...

Comment: @JosephGarvin: You should use `std::uintptr_t` from `<cstdint>` if it's available to you.

Comment: Now that I look at this again I don't think it's correct. 'offset' is going to be a large pointer address with just some of the bottom bits zeroed out. I think you mean "offset = obj - ((unsigned long)obj & ~(N-1))"? That or remove the "~"?

Comment: @AntoineMathys: true, but only if N is a compile-time constant.